# Sitemap and get_absolute_url

Tags: django, django-models

i make my sitemap and have an interrogation about to get only my objects that have a valid url, explain :

for exemple my events can have divers url, a dedicated page, a simple link to a pdf, a redirection to other page of my site or other site or simply no url.

In my sitemap i do this for only get event that have an url :

```
def items(self):
    events = Event.objects.all()
    event_array = []
    for event in events:
        if event.get_absolute_url():
            event_array.append(event)

    return event_array
```

That's work, but i have look at model managers and i think it can do this for me too, so my question is : it is better to have a model manager for this or my way to do this is good?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your Model Manager is here to do jobs like this. Create a method that filter all event with an url.
Read this part of the documentation for more details : [Django 1.8 - Model Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/)

E.g :

```python
from django.db import models

class EventManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(EventManager, self).get_queryset().all()

    def with_url():
        return self.get_query_set().exclude(url__isnull=True, url__exact='')


class Event(models.Model):
    objects = EventManager()
```

Comment: Thanks i'll do this then

Comment: I have added an example of what your code should looks like

Comment: Thanks you save me some hours ^^, i have try to deal directly with get_absolute_url method but without success^^. A strange problem has appear, after do this all of my events without absolute url was deleted of my database,can't create event without url in admin interface and can't perform normal queryset in my event like Event.objects.filter(visible = True), will re-read the doc about this...

Comment: ok... items aren't deleted, i have had a default manager "objects = models.Manager()" and its fine now ^^". Bye

Comment: Sorry mate, I did a mistake, I forget to implemet `get_queryset`, i have updated my anwser, it should work now :)